# How to change values which get from check box into SQL condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use check_box_tag to get selected beacon, and i to use collection_select to define a value. when user press the button, I want to all selected beacons change value into what collection_select choose, but I don't know how to use ids[] to set my condition like **"where...in ..."**

here is my action, I want `params[:ids]` change in to just like `[1,2,3]`

```
@beacons = Beacon.where(:id => params[:ids]).update_all(:installer_id => params[:account][:installer_id])
```

here is my table:

```
<table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">

       <thead class="cf">
        <th>Check</th>
        <th>BeaconUUID</th>
        <th>BeaconCategory</th>
        <th>BeaconLocate</th>
        <th>BeaconName</th>
        <th>BeaconAddress</th>
        <th>Assign</th>
       </thead>
      <tbody>
          <% @beacons.each do |beacon| %>
            <tr>
              <td><%= check_box_tag "ids[]", beacon.id %></td>
              <td><%= beacon.beacon_uuid %></td>
              <td><%= beacon.cid %></td>
              <td><%= beacon.lid %></td>
              <td><%= beacon.beacon_name %></td>
              <td><%= beacon.beacon_address %></td>
              <% if beacon.installer_id.nil? %> 
                <td>not assign</td>
              <% else %>
                <td>assigned:<%= beacon.installer_id %></td>
              <% end %>

            </tr>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>    
</table>

<%= form_tag assigned_beacons_path, :method => 'post' do %>
  <td><%= collection_select(:account, :installer_id, Account.where('manager_id = ?',session[:user_id]), :id, :email, {:prompt => 'choose!'}, :style => "width: 100px;") %></td>
  <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><%= submit_tag 'assign', class: "btn btn-info btn-xs"%></p></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to move check_box_tag inside of form_tag block. What happens if you move your `<%= form_tag ... do %>` line to the top of provided snippet?

Comment: thank you!!! I move the form_tag and change some code into @beacons = Beacon.where(params[:beacon_ids]).update_all(:installer_id => params[:account][:installer_id]), and it work! but even I am not selected, It still update all...

Comment: finally! it should be map to int!
ids = params[:beacon_ids].map{|i| i.to_i} 
    @beacons = Beacon.where(id: ids).update_all(:installer_id => params[:account][:installer_id])

Comment: It's not required to map to int, Rails will auto-convert array of Strings into integer values when making query. If you don't mind, you could accept my advice as an answer :)

Comment: I tried before, you are right! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out in comments, `check_box_tag` should be moved inside of form_tag block:

```
<%= form_tag assigned_beacons_path, :method => 'post' do %>
  <table class="col-md-12 table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf">

         <thead class="cf">
          <th>Check</th>
          <th>BeaconUUID</th>
          <th>BeaconCategory</th>
          <th>BeaconLocate</th>
          <th>BeaconName</th>
          <th>BeaconAddress</th>
          <th>Assign</th>
         </thead>
        <tbody>
            <% @beacons.each do |beacon| %>
              <tr>
                <td><%= check_box_tag "ids[]", beacon.id %></td>
                <td><%= beacon.beacon_uuid %></td>
                <td><%= beacon.cid %></td>
                <td><%= beacon.lid %></td>
                <td><%= beacon.beacon_name %></td>
                <td><%= beacon.beacon_address %></td>
                <% if beacon.installer_id.nil? %> 
                  <td>not assign</td>
                <% else %>
                  <td>assigned:<%= beacon.installer_id %></td>
                <% end %>

              </tr>
          <% end %>
        </tbody>    
  </table>
  <td><%= collection_select(:account, :installer_id, Account.where('manager_id = ?',session[:user_id]), :id, :email, {:prompt => 'choose!'}, :style => "width: 100px;") %></td>
  <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit"><%= submit_tag 'assign', class: "btn btn-info btn-xs"%></p></td>
<% end %>
```

Also, dangling `<td>` blocks don't look good, you should move them into this or another `<table>` as well.

Comment: why dangling <td> blocks don't look good? can you explain more detail??

Comment: Because `<td>` without `<table>` will be stripped out by modern browsers. You should use `<td>`s only inside of `<table>`. By the way, press the check mark near my answer to accept it, if you considered it useful.